# Visual Studio 2015 error 'type universe cannot resolve assembly' after adding NuGet package

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-mobile-services

I'm just trying to simple take the default 'to do item' project that Azure generates and make it work offline with a local database. The code was already written into it, and all I needed to do was add in a NuGet Package ( Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore) and build it.

There's too much code to post here and according to VS the error is with the package and not the project so I have no idea what would be relevant to post. The code can be found here: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Jq-WQVQeXiooE4TIV6tOKP2gZhmr39tJ

Sometimes it will run but will only open a black window instead of the XAML. Most of the time I get the 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version 1.3.0.0..." and "cannot resolve Assembly or Windows metadata file 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll'".

Any help would be super appreciated. The only fixes I've seen were to allow NuGet to check for missing files and download them. I've enabled this and it doesn't changed anything.

Comment: It seems to me that you have an earlier version of the Mobile Package installed. If you are up to date with all the latest service packs etc for VS2015, there is likely to be a versioning conflict. I would remove the windowsAzure Mobile package and reinstall through package manager. Leave the version number off so that it installs the latest version. See what happens after that.

Comment: After doing that, I get these errors, plus the original two
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RRql9fmKXnteJWLh0RwcLEyAK7ZgKZW0

Comment: Basically you are have 2 different and conflicting libraries installed according to that error, and as such the compiler doesn't know which one it should use. You either need to remove one of the references or be explicit in the reference to the library you wish to use. In general this proves that you have an issue with versioning though.

Comment: That makes sense. What doesn't make sense is the conflicting libraries are both installed from one NuGet package... When I delete one of the reference I get an error for it being gone.

Comment: they should be separate libraries. The trouble you might have is that there might still be other libraries installed that rely on the one you have removed (dependency). You would need to remove these as well.

Comment: If you are not running the latest SDK,install it from here:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/downloads/archive-net-downloads/, and then re-try.